# The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts paypal express checkout

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment

I have read other posts on the very same subject but I didn't get solution. Below code is working code and I have used this code multiple times but don't know what I am doing wrong right now,

Below is $padata:

```
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
RETURNURL=My return link
CANCELURL=My cancel link
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Vancouver
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=1799.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Ottawa
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=1799.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME2=Calgary
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY2=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT2=1799.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME3=YoloMD+Verify+Facility
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY3=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT3=599.00
NOSHIPPING=1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=5996.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=0
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=2398.40
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=0
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=3597.60
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
LOCALECODE=GB
LOGOIMG=My logo
CARTBORDERCOLOR=1761a9
ALLOWNOTE=1
```

**Calling Method -**

```
$paypal->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);
```

**Response Received**

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2016%2d07%2d13T09%3a22%3a38Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 879b5f075c7c1
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 109%2e0
    [BUILD] => 23255924
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument%2e See additional error messages for details%2e
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts%2e
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT should be specified as a negative number. For example:
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=-2398.40

More detailed introduction, please check [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/).